# How to access variables of nested arrays in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs

I am sending data from **javascript** to my **php** server. But I can't access all my variables sent. There are some nested arrays and JSON strings and I just can't figure out how to access them.

Here my code:

### sender.js

```
$scope.report = {
    'title': '',
    'desc': '',
    'address': {
        'text': '',
        'lat': '',
        'lng': ''
    },
    'tags': ['none chosen']
};



function postToServer () {
var data = {
    'do': 'addNewReportToDatabase',
    'data': {
        'usr': userId,
        'report': JSON.stringify($scope.report)
    }
};
$http({
    url: $rootScope.server_url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert(response);
});
}
```

### server.php

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $data = json_decode(json_encode($request->data), True);
    if (isset($request->do)) {
        switch ($request->do) {
            case 'addNewReportToDatabase':
                $reportStr = $data['report'];
                $reportJSON = json_decode($reportStr);
                echo $reportJSON['title'];
                break;
        }
    }
```

I can't access any variables of my report-variable.

I CAN say `echo json_encode($reportJSON);` and if I log it in my **JS** the response I get is an *Object* with all my variables as it's supposed to be!

**The stringified version looks then like this:** `{"title":"title","desc":"describtion","address":{"text":"address","lat":"","lng":""},"tags":["Unfall","Terrorismus","Regional"]}`

If I user `var_dump($reportJSON);` I get the following output:

```
"object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["title"]=> string(5) "title" ["desc"]=> string(11) "describtion" ["address"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["text"]=> string(7) "address" ["lat"]=> string(0) "" ["lng"]=> string(0) "" } ["tags"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Unfall" [1]=> string(11) "Terrorismus" [2]=> string(8) "Regional" } } "
```

So why can't I access the variables with my php??

Comment: Why bother stringifying `'report'`? Just send it as is.

Comment: Try debugging with `var_dump($request)` and work your way through each level of your array.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be one possability! 
I am storing it in localstorage so I needed to stringify it. But it works. 

Even so is there an other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `report` as an Associative array instead of an object.

Your `echo $reportJSON['title']` should be insetead:

`echo $reportJSON->title;`

since in your `var_dump`, `$reportJSON`  is of type: `object(stdClass)#3...`.

Personally I like to work with JSON data as objects, kind of makes the code easier to read and avoids Undefined indexes notices on some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set second param to `true` at `json_decode()` if you want to access like that.

Change to this line (in server.php):

```
$reportJSON = json_decode($reportStr, true); // <-- add second param true
```